# Record Not Saved Cloudkit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cloudkit

hello so i am following this tutorial: https://medium.com/better-programming/data-persistence-cloudkit-b12e575bd85c
and i followed step by step but i get this error when i save: Record Not Saved
this is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit
import MobileCoreServices

class CloudKitViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textfield: UITextField!
    let privateDatabase = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
    var titles = [String]()
   var recordIDs = [CKRecord.ID]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    @IBAction func saveBtn(_ sender: Any) {

          let title = textfield.text!

                let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Note")

                record.setValue(title, forKey: "title")

                privateDatabase.save(record) { (savedRecord, error) in

                    if error == nil {

                        print("Record Saved")

                    } else {

                        print("Record Not Saved")

                    }

                }

     }
```

can someone help :)
Edit:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with the setup of the iCloud container. You can check this in CloudKit Dashboard. You need to make sure you have created a “Note” record type that includes a “title” key.

Also ensure that CloudKit is enabled in the app capabilities section in Xcode.

You could try printing the actual error to get more information to aid debugging:

```
let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Note")
record["title"] = title // Try setting the value using subscripting (it has worked for me)
privateDatabase.save(record) { (savedRecord, error) in
    if error == nil {
        print("Record Saved")
    } else {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

There is more information available about `CKError` in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckerror).

Also, if you are using CloudKit Dashboard to check the value has been saved, be sure to refresh it.

Comment: it prints Record Not Saved :(

Comment: Try adding a record manually in CloudKit Dashboard on the web and seeing if the tutorial code retrieves it.

Comment: i updated the code, im new to cloudkit so i dont really know how to do that

Comment: @MYZXI I’ve changed my code so it will print more details of the error rather than just “Record not saved” - are what it says

Comment: Value of type 'Error?' has no member 'localisedDescription'

Comment: @MYZXI Hang on! It’s `localizedDescription` (American spelling with a Z)

Comment: Optional("This request requires an authenticated account")
thats the error

Comment: @MYZXI Ah, are you using simulator? I think it needs a real device with iCloud account. If running in Simulator, try going to settings on simulator (like you would on iPhone) and logging in iCloud account. It will need to be same account you use for development I think.

Comment: Optional("Couldn\'t get container configuration from the server for container \"iCloud.com.****.SalonAppv2\"")

Comment: @MYZXI Hmm. Getting out of my depth. It’s a problem with the setup of the iCloud container - might be fixable on Dashboard, or make sure you have enabled CloudKit in the capabilities. Some advice here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110786

Comment: how to make a container, sorry im new

Comment: @MYZXI No problem :) Try the advice near the start of this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4878052-cloudkit-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: @MYZXI Did you have any success?

Comment: @MYZXI Great! No problem

Comment: @MYZXI Can I ask what you had to do to get it working in the end?

Comment: @MYZXI I made all sorts of mistakes the first time I used CloudKit! Glad you for it working.